# What are the /BLOCKED urls within Google Analytics?

Tags: url, google-analytics

I noticed some weird urls when going through Google Analytics. Did some research and can not find out what they are. Can anybody shed any light? [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not an Analytics dependent thing. This is a custom configuration you have when you send the pageview or a plugin or widget you have on the site or spam traffic.